# Why can we say "He was being rude to me", but can't say "He was behaving rude to me"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Saw this [info](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be_2)

> To be [linking verb]: to behave in a particular way
>
> He was just being rude.
>
> Don't be silly.
>
> You'd better be careful.

So, we can say "**He was just being rude.**" but why can't we say "**He was just behaving rude.**"

We can only say "**He was just behaving rudely.**"

So, what is the main reason?

Comment: "He was just behaving rude" is ungrammatical because "behave" does not take predicative complements like "be" does. Instead it requires a manner complement, typically an AdvP like "rudely", "appallingly", "badly", and the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of "to be" as a linking verb which you cite ("to behave in a particular way") does not imply that the verbs "to be" and "to behave" can be used interchangeably.

The verb **to be** is "special" in English, as it is in most languages. **To be** is complemented (or modified) by an adjective, and not by an adverb, as is the case with most verbs, such as "to behave."